# PHP async without system calls

Tags: php

Due to an attack on our server last year, I have blocked all system calls via php:

```
## php.ini
disable_functions = exec, passthru, shell_exec, system, proc_open, popen, curl_exec, curl_multi_exec, parse_ini_file, show_source, eval
```

But this has stopped my async function working which is used to send email in the background.

Is there a purely php 'safe' way to make an async call without opening up the exec() function again ?

```
function doEmail($subject,$body,$to){                    
    $pwd = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    $body = urlencode($body);
    $subject = urlencode($subject);
    $mailpage = $pwd."/email.php";
    $command = "$mailpage $subject $body $to";
    bgExecute($command);    

}

## Asyncronous PHP - Multi-Tasking (Email etc)
function bgExecute($command) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") pclose(popen("start /B ". $command, "r"));  // Windows
    $exec = "/usr/bin/php -f $command > /dev/null &"; // Ubuntu
    exec($exec);    
}
```

Comment: A different path might be to make a web service call to a separate service that you delegate this to.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: The basic idea is to pass the information to a different process/system that has the ability to do the job. You could do this by setup a web service (another web server listening for the email information). You could also write it to a local file, and have some other process pick it up. I'm sure there are other solutions to pass the info (sockets/middleware/etc).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to keep sending arbitrary commands without allowing sending arbitrary commands, then no.

If what you are asking is if there is way to execute external applications on demand from PHP, then yes.

One way would be to write your commands to a file and have another process that actually monitors that file for change.

```
$filename = '/tmp/myfile.txt';
$prevMtime = 0;
while (true) {
  clearstatcache();
  //Do it in two steps just in case you have PHP < 5.4
  $mtime = stat($filename);
  $mtime = $mtime['mtime'];

  if ($mtime > $prevMtime) {
    $prevMtime = $mtime;
    print("file ${filename} changed\n");
  }
  usleep(10);
}
```

Another would be to use sockets to achieve the same thing.

The thing is that neither of those solutions is a silver bullet: if you just allow arbitrary commands to be executed, then you gain little to no security.

You need to define how much security you want. Then you need to decide how much flexibility you want.

One way it could be done is by having a process (socket or file based) that you configure to only execute a certain list of executables and have your PHP send commands to it.